# How to filter the documents by most used by the clients

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have aggregate function to perform the compare the two tables. And I need to return the documents by most used by the clients.
It's possible to do with server side. If not please guide me through proper way

Thanks

Comment: Could you provide document examples, what did you try so far? It's difficult without seeing the document structure

Comment: you can use a in-memory data structure store, like Redis
 https://redis.io/topics/introduction

Comment: Bit large document

Comment: Filter like most used hotels first based on the views

Comment: If you monitor your logs from the http server you may run periodical  script to analyze the access and increment a value with number of hits per day so later you can easily sort by this value...